# How can I automatically merge duplicated textures with his users, and materials using that textures?

Tags: texturing, materials

I got a model that has lot of duplicated textures and duplicated materials and I want to know how can I merge all duplicated textures and materials in a automatic way.(I mean by not selecting each texture by hand)

Comment: Hello :). You can use the *Remap* function in the Outliner, or are you looking for a script?

Comment: Say, I didn’t know about that. I’ll have to look into it. But for now, are the core data blocks like images duplicated, or does it just go as deep as materials,